# htaccess not redirecting all not found page or URL on site to 404 pages

Tags: .htaccess

Try to set 404 page not found error page by htaccess.

Issue is if we are searching for 
https://www.rsseosolution.com/suraj.html ... Its redirect perfect to 404.php.
But if we are searching for 
https://www.rsseosolution.com/suraj.php ... Its not redirecting to 404.php and giving showing simple text message "File not found.".

In short problem is if extension is not php then its redirecting fine but if .php then its showing File not found.

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.rsseosolution.com/404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule seo-package-(.*)-n-(.*)\.php$ seo-package-detail.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule case-studies/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ case-studies.php?project=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule tutorial/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ tutorial.php?topic=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule blog-page-(.*)\.php$ blog.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule seo-tutorial-(.*)\.php$ seo-tutorial.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule frequently-ask-question-faq-(.*)\.php$ frequently-ask-question-faq.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

What i am looking for is ....... redirect all not found or wrong URL to 404.php.

What i am missing here.

I think because we are rewriting some URLs with .php extension from htaccess and thats why for PHP its saying file not found but for other its redirecting perfectly to 404.php.

Is there any ways to set 404.php for all not found pages and URL without change any extension (.php) of previous written file by htaccess.

Comment: Do you have access to the main server config?

Comment: I am pretty sure I’ve told you in the past already how fundamentally wrong `ErrorDocument 404 https://www.rsseosolution.com/404.php` is - this will cause an external redirect, so that the request for the original URL will not be correctly answered with a 404 status code any more.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes @MrWhite i am using VPS and i have access of my server (Plesk).

Comment: @04FS i changed 404 line in htaccess to `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` but still my problem not resolve ..... if domain.com/suraj.html (redirecting fine) but domain.com/suraj.php (Saying File not found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not to do with your current directives in `.htaccess`.

The problem is mostly likely due to your server config and the way PHP is implemented on your server. If requests for `.php` files are proxied to a backend server for processing as is often the case with FastCGI type configs then this 404 Not Found message is likely coming from the backend server and not your Apache server.

Ordinarily, you would solve this with the [`ProxyErrorOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride) directive in the reverse proxy config:

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

If you don't have access to the main server config then you may be able to trigger the 404 early using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`, before the request is sent to the proxy server.

For example, before your existing mod_rewrite directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

However, this is strictly a "workaround", if you have access to the server config then using `ProxyErrorOverride` (as mentioned above) is preferable.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 https://www.rsseosolution.com/404.php
> ```

By specifying an absolute URL in the `ErrorDocument` directive this triggers an *external* (302) redirect for the error document (an additional request), which is generally undesirable (and you need to manually set the 404 response code). It is far better to issue the error document as an internal subrequest instead:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Added 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]`
And now its working fine ..... all 404 page or unknown URL redirect perfectly to 404.php page. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working. Note, however, that using that mod_rewrite is really a "workaround". If you have access to the main server config (as you say you do), then "fixing" the server config is preferable.